# Copy and paste values in google sheet with macro dont work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste, google-sheets-macros

When I paste values from a formula with macro in google sheet the cell show empty

I need to copy the result of =now but only with values, the problem is that don't copy anything, for the example, y write the =now formula in F2 and I need to copy only the values in D2

```
spreadsheet.getRange('F2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=NOW()');
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

I need that paste values to save this moment if I copy the formula its update in every change and it is no valid for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function macro1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange('F2').activate();
  sh.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=NOW()');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  sh.getRange('D2').activate();
  sh.getRange('F2').copyTo(sh.getActiveRange(),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```